# SQL Recursion, Retrieve Orders based on Product and parent Product

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I would like an SQL query that returns 'Orders' based on the associated 'Product', the 'Product.DepositId' has to equal an exact integer value (for example Product.DepositId = 1).

If the associated 'Product.DepositId' is null, then the query needs to go up the Product ladder get the parent 'Product' using 'Product.ParentId' and so on.

- A 'Product' parent hierarchy can go 'N' tiers/layers. (for example Child -> ChildParent -> ChildParent -> Final Parent)
- Multiple 'Product' children can be associated to the same Parent
- Only the top most parent 'Product' will have a DepositId. So if the 'Product.ParentId' is null then the 'Product.DepositId' will not be null
- An 'Order' can be associated with a child 'Product' or with a parent 'Product'. (Parents can have orders as well.)

For example (to make the example simple I used integer ids instead of uniqueidentifier)

Products

```
Id  ParentId  DepositId
1   NULL      10
2   NULL      20
3   1         NULL
4   2         NULL
5   1         NULL
6   3         NULL
```

Orders

```
Id      ProductId
1001    1
1002    2
1003    3
1004    4
1005    5
1006    6
```

Expected Result Orders with DepositId = 10

```
OrderId  ProductId
1001     1           --Because Product 1 DepositId = 10
1003     3           --Because Product 3 is child of Product 1
1005     5           --Because Product 5 is child of Product 1
1006     6           --Because Product 6 is child of Product 3 which in 
                       turn is a child of Product 1
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a recursive CTE.

> ```
> ;with rcte_products as (
>   select Id as ProductId, ParentId
>   , DepositId
>   , 0 as Lvl
>   , Id as BaseId
>   from Products
>   where DepositId = 10
>   
>   union all
>   
>   select t.Id, t.ParentId
>   , c.DepositId
>   , c.Lvl+1
>   , c.BaseId
>   from rcte_products c
>   join Products t on t.ParentId = c.ProductId
> )
> select 
>   o.Id as OrderId
> , o.ProductId
> from rcte_products c
> join Orders o 
>   on o.ProductId = c.ProductId
> order by o.Id;
> ```

| OrderId | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1003 | 3 |
| 1005 | 5 |
| 1006 | 6 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=11bca7990a47cbb9a8a97b440df66780)*

Comment: Fyi, the DepositId & Lvl & BaseId can be removed from the CTE. It's just extra info for testing the recursion.